# toString() method is not inherting from its super class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, tostring

I'm working on a task which has the following classes:

1. `Vehicle.java` ( Abstract Class)
2. `NewVehicle.java` subClass of `Vehicle.java`
3. `UsedVehicle.java` subClass of `Vehicle.java`
4. `VehicleParser.java` used as a parser
5. `Drive` Class which is used as main

In the `VehicleParser` class I determine which object it is. Either it is a `NewVehicle` object or a `UsedVehicle`. And in the `Drive` class I fill an `ArrayList` with the `Vehicle` objects.

Now When I'm trying to `System.out.println` an `Arraylist` the drive class is just invoking `toString` method declared in `UsedVehicle`/`NewVehicle` but not invoking the method declared in the `Vehicle.java` class. I need it to first invoke the method `toString` of Vehicle and then concat the `toString` of `UsedVehicle`/`NewVehicle` with it.

Here is the Code:

**Vehicle**

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

    protected String make;
    protected int modelYear;
    protected String motivePower;
    protected double licenseFee;

    public Vehicle(String make,int modeYear,String motivePower) {
        this.make = make;
        this.modelYear= modeYear;
        this.motivePower = motivePower;
        this.licenseFee = 0.0;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public int getModelYear() {
        return modelYear;
    }

    public void setModelYear(int modelYear) {
        this.modelYear = modelYear;
    }

    public String getMotivePower() {
        return motivePower;
    }

    public void setMotivePower(String motivePower) {
        this.motivePower = motivePower;
    }

    public double getLicenseFee() {
        return licenseFee;
    }

    public void setLicenseFee(double licenseFee) {
        this.licenseFee = licenseFee;
    }

    public abstract void computeLicenseFee();

    public String toString()
    {
        return "\nMake:\t\t"+getMake()+
                "\nModel Year:\t"+getModelYear()+
                "\n Motive Power:\t"+getMotivePower()+
                "\nLicense Fee:\t"+getLicenseFee();
    }

    public static class UsedVehicle extends Vehicle
    {
        public String previousLicenseState;
        public int currentYear;
        int yearsOld = 0;

        public UsedVehicle(String make, int modelYear, String power, String previousState, int currentYear)
        {
            super(make,modelYear,power);
            this.previousLicenseState = previousState;
            this.currentYear = currentYear;
        }


        public String getPreviousLicenseState() {
            return previousLicenseState;
        }


        public void setPreviousLicenseState(String previousLicenseState) {
            this.previousLicenseState = previousLicenseState;
        }


        public int getCurrentYear() {
            return currentYear;
        }


        public void setCurrentYear(int currentYear) {
            this.currentYear = currentYear;
        }


        public void computeLicenseFee() {
            double baseFee = 100.00;
            double titleTransferFee = 15.00;
            double smogWaiverFee = 0.00;
            double smogAbatement = 0.00;

            yearsOld = getCurrentYear() - getModelYear();
            if(yearsOld > 5)
            {
                smogWaiverFee = 8.00;
            }

            if("gas".equalsIgnoreCase(getMotivePower()))
            {
                smogAbatement = 20.00;
            }

            licenseFee = baseFee + smogAbatement + titleTransferFee + smogWaiverFee; 
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "\n Years Old:\t"+yearsOld+
                    "\n Previous State:\t"+getPreviousLicenseState();
        }
    }

    public static class NewVehicle extends Vehicle
    {
        public double vehiclePrice;

        public NewVehicle(String make, int modeYear, String motivePower,double price) {
            super(make, modeYear, motivePower);
            this.vehiclePrice = price;
        }


        public double getVehiclePrice() {
            return vehiclePrice;
        }


        public void setVehiclePrice(double vehiclePrice) {
            this.vehiclePrice = vehiclePrice;
        }


        public void computeLicenseFee() {

            double baseFee = 150.00;
            double smogAbatement = 0.00;
            double priceFee = 0.00;

            if("gas".equalsIgnoreCase(getMotivePower()))
            {
                smogAbatement = 20.0;
                priceFee = getVehiclePrice()*0.15;
            }

            licenseFee = baseFee + smogAbatement + priceFee; 
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "Price:\t\t$"+getVehiclePrice();
        }
    }
}
```

**Parser**

```
public class VehicleParser {

    public static Vehicle parseStringToVehicle(String lineToParse)
    {
        Vehicle vehicleObj = null;

        Vehicle.UsedVehicle usedVeh = new Vehicle.UsedVehicle(make, modelYear, power, previousState, currentYear);

        return vehicleObj;
    }
}
```

**DriveClass**

```
 Vehicle obj = VehicleParser.parseStringToVehicle(inputInfo);
 vehicleList.add(obj);
 System.out.println(vehicleList.get(i));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overriding the `toString()` method. Java doesn't do any special magic here. If you want the super class' method to be called, you need to do so explicitly with the `super` keyword:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + // Here
            "\n Years Old:\t"+yearsOld+
            "\n Previous State:\t"+getPreviousLicenseState();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just consider this example:

```
public class A {
    public String someMethod() {
        return "A method";
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public String someMethod() {
        return "B method";
    }
}

public class C extends B {
    @Override
    public String someMethod() {
        return "C method";
    }
}
```

Basically what's going on here is that when you inherit the parent class, **you're overriding everything that's in parent class's method and you're giving new definition to it.** By *Overriding parent class's method*, you're saying that:

> I'm giving a new fresh definition to this method. From now onward, for all of my objects and my child's object, this is only going to be the definition that would be considered and any of parent's method definition is void.

Now if you want the parent's method definition to be called before calling this method definition, then you'd have to specifically state that using `super.methodName()` in your code.

```
public class A {
    public String someMethod() {
        return "A method";
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public String someMethod() {
        return super.someMethod() + "B method";
    }
}

public class C extends B {
    @Override
    public String someMethod() {
        return super.someMethod() + "C method";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the subclass methods the overridden methods will be called and all the definitions in the parent's method will be overridden and you will get only the overridden method definition. So inprder to use the parents' method definition as well you need to use the `super()` method in your child class method...

```
return super.toString() + " is a new car!";
```